# How can I best formulate my glmm if i want to test within individuals and within context for these individuals?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, repeated-measures, glmm, glmmtmb

I am a beginner in using glmm, I have a question about which structure to test "within individual and within context". I have collected vocal data on 12 different individuals (animals) in a "before/after" setting. I want to test if there are differences in vocal parameters before and after within individual while also comparing the same contexts within these individuals. There are other factors that I want to account for, namely age and sex. It is important that the model tests within individual, and within these individuals also within context. If this is possible, what is the correct structure for the glmm to do this in R?

Currently, I have (simple example):
`glmmTMB(Parameter~Time + (1|Individual) + (1|Context) + Age + Sex, data=mydata)`

Is this correct or would I have to use something like `(1|Individual:Context)` or `(1|Individual/Context)`?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to CV! What kind of variable is context? How many levels does context have? Also, how many observations per animal and how many in total you have?

Comment: Thank you! Context is categorical. Examples are: Receiving aggression from the mother, Receiving aggression from adult females, vocalising towards the mother. There are 9 different contexts. Each animal was observed for 4 hours (2 hours before and after), but ofcourse not all animals have vocalised the same amount, so there is a different amount of vocalisations for each individual.

Comment: OK! It sounds you have several observations of the same contexts from different animals (as well as several observations of each animal from different contexts and times). In this case, your first (simple) model is correct. The latter models specify animal and context random effects as nested, but they don't seem to be nested in your design (if each animal went through different, animal-specific contexts, then nested model would be correct).